# Should under slab basement plumbing include a trap for the shower?

Tags: plumbing, basement

[image]Paid  builder for basement under slab plumbing consisting of a drain for shower, sink, toilet and bucket. They did not include a trap for the shower. So, the eventual basement work to put in a bathroom required a jackhammer to install a trap.  I thought I originally paid for the rough plumbing to avoid that aspect of work later.  The original builder claims that they did the entire job.  I disagree, since they did not install the trap. Who is correct?

A little more information. The basement slab plumbing was an option provided by the builder in case the owner wanted to add a bathroom in the future. There were pipes showing above the floor of the basement as well as a pit for an ejector pump (See photo). Several year later, I hired someone to finish part of the basement including the bathroom. They found the lack of a trap and remedied the situation to avoid sewer gases. I would have expected a trap to have been installed by the original builder since it would definitely be required.

Thank you to everyone who responded for the input provided.  I am sorry that I posed a question that was not DIY-related.  I happened to find this forum and was impressed by the high caliber of responses.  I was really just looking to determine if the original builder (who has an excellent reputation, but has been passed on to the next generation and seems to have done some shoddy work recently) was yet again trying to feed me a line of bull. As a widow, I feel that I have been taken advantage of by them on more than one occasion.  Again, I thank you all for your thoughtful comments. I do try to educate myself as much as possible and appreciate any and all input.

Comment: What _did_ they include for the shower? A capped stub of pipe buried somewhere under the concrete? Was the builder given sufficient information to understand precisely where the P-trap opening should have been placed? (I note also that this question is opinion-based and does not ask a DIY question.)

Comment: Consult your local code. Was this permitted work? What was the outcome of the inspection? Obviously you need a p-trap somewhere along the DWV if not a P-trap right at the drain itself. I mean, is there sewer gas coming out of the shower?

Comment: What they did provide is in the photo that I just included.  I am sure that it was included under the original building permit. There is no sewer gas because the missing trap was discovered by the person putting in the bathroom and remedied.

Comment: In addition to Maureen's input it is OBVIOUS that the pipes were laid out to be put in place there.    You see the sink drain on the wall that will hold the column.    Toilet seems a little close to wall but doable and the bath/shower extends to wall.    Sink, toilet, shower...

Comment: Obviously what we've ended up with here is an opinion poll. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 5):

Showers are usually roughed into an *approximate* location, with a boxed out area in the slab for final positioning and the (later) installation of a trap. This is common and expected as wall and shower pan position and design can vary. Any form lumber is usually removed after the pour and the cavity filled with gravel or washed rock after the trap is put in. Here's an example:

[image]
<sub>[source](https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=25302)</sub>

If a mistake was made it was that this boxed-out area wasn't provided. Of course, your contract should've been clear on these points if you had specific expectations. If it wasn't, that's mostly on you.

Oh, and a jackhammer wasn't the ideal tool for the job. A wet diamond saw would be much less destructive and less likely to crack up the slab outside the repair area.

Comment: I would like to see comments on where people have seen this.   I have done work in the south, northwest, mainly midwest and in europe.   I have inspected thousands of homes and have never seen a rough in like that in my life.   I am not saying it doesn't exist.   I am just commenting that it certainly isn't normal and must be very regional in your area.

Comment: Also she has a picture of the rough in.   Her picture I have seen thousands of times.   Yours none.    Why would you answer that it should have a box when it doesn't and I am not sure your answer is normal.    Also I don't know many subs that will bust out a wet diamond saw for that kind of job.    Even watching Holmes' crew do basements on his show... they use sledgehammers for small jobs.

Comment: I have never seen a rough in "box" as shown in the pic submitted .  But that shows how this is a regional thing.  That said the builder should have had a box for the shower drain and not just a pipe  out of the slab.  Either a box or the trap under the slab should have been done . The builder missed this one.

Comment: It makes more sense if you've finished a few basements and know how finicky it can be to fit plumbing walls, a 60" tub, and whatever's on the other side with pipe set by plumbers who may not have a high degree of precision and then bumped around by carpenters and masons for a few weeks.

Comment: I had my basement built with roughed-in plumbing and it looks exactly like the OP's picture. I wasn't told about the need for digging out the concrete later to fit in a trap. It's exactly what I wanted to avoid. Now I am armed with more information when I eventually do install a bathroom, so I thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3):

The builder did not give you a functional shower drain if that is what you paid for.    In fact it would have cost the builder $4 and 2-3 minutes time to just add it.

The builder might have assumed that this shower drain was just an approximation and might be moved once home owner has the basement layout plans done.    But you know what assuming gets you...

I for one put this on the builder 100% if you can prove your plans where adjusted to keep the drain in the same spot.    I have used the exact location of basement rough-ins (almost randomly put in) and got creative about the bathrooms/shower/sink layout.    It really isn't that hard unless your drains are too close to the out walls or almost in the center.

So as judge I rule in favor of home owner here.   Code requires a p trap.    Builder is negligent for spraying sewer gases from half-ass work.   Like I said a couple bucks and couple minutes to do it right.

On a side note... I am not sure adding a p-trap is jackhammer worthy.    You just need to move small strip of concrete (2 feet?) times 4 inches deep.   A sledgehammer and a couple buckets usually does it.

Comment: No one said anything about sewer gases. As a home buyer I'd _rather_ have exact position left to me. I'd much rather set a trap myself where it fits than try to position walls and the shower pan to the plumbing, especially if there are further limitations imposed by vent stacks nearby.

Comment: Sewer gases were avoided by the addition of the missing trap by the person putting in the bathroom.  The layout was predetermined with the placement of all of the pipes in advance.

Comment: @isherwood - it isn't hard to figure out a layout that uses a decent position.    Obviously I have redone my fair share of basements - that's the money maker for a lot of houses.   I get you want it where you want it.    I will leave it where it is instead of moving it 8 inches and save myself $500 and a half day.

Comment: I'll go with a diamond saw first and then a sledgehammer to avoid having to repair more concrete than required.

Answer (score 2):

This well may be a regional issue and what is common practice in that particular area.

Where I am in Florida, there are thousands of homes built on a slab.  The shower drains all are plumbed with a trap under the slab.

If you are in florida, I would say the builder did not do the job correctly.  That may not be the issue where your are.  ( However I still do not understand how the builder would expect a trap to be added after the slab was poured.)

Maybe ask other builders in your location, if they were contracted to "stub out" a bathroom with a shower, would it include a trap.

Comment: I am in complete agreement.   Maybe this is a regional thing.   I have literally never seen the picture isherwood showed at thousands of homes over the past 30 years.     The only time I have seen anything like that was a new home going up and the builder was doing the bathroom.